# What options are available for rendering a embedded adobe PDF in a page frame?

Tags: pdf, documents, embedded

What options are available for rendering a embedded adobe PDF in a page frame?

Options I would like to set, if anyone knows what they are:

1. Fit page to width  (not just height)
2. Dont show left nav tabs
3. Dont show review/comment buttons
4. Dont show "view options menu bar"
5. I do want to show the "file save/search menu bar"
6. Open in continuous mode by default

So, is it possible to generate a embedded PDF that has these options set for the Adobe IE8 plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this PDF document that gives the variables that you can set for displaying a PDF document. It is set to use page 5 which gives an intro to the practice of displaying within a URL. Looks like there is a decent amount of options available for you.

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/pdf_creation_apis_and_specs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#page=5